# Php Include() Issues

Tags: php

I am having three files which are as follows

1. users.php
2. auth.php
3. main.php

where `users.php` is located at root of the directory `/` . auth and `main.php` is located into the test folder example `/test/auth.php` & `/test/main.php`.

`Users.php` containing following php code.

```
<?php 
include('test/main.php');
?>
```

`auth.php` containing following php code.

```
<?php 
include('../test/main.php');
?>
```

main.php code

```
<?php
include('test/db.php');
?>
```

Where i am executing `users.php` it is working perfectly but when i am executing `users.php` which is located at root folder gives me output perfect but if i am executing `/test/auth.php`

```
Warning: include(test/db.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/db.php on line 2
```

is there any solution to access `auth.php`  with error with proper function.

Comment: Just enter the right location.

Comment: include('/test/main.php');

Comment: your warning specifies "db.php", but db.php isn't listed above as one of your files, only users, main, and auth

Comment: @jussi Same error  Warning: include(/test/db.php)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes are always *relative to the working directory* (actually, relative to the *PATH*, of which the working directory is a part). The working directory is determined by the *script that's being executed.* Say you have this structure:

```
webroot/
    foo.php
    folder/
        bar.php
```

When you run `foo.php` either through `$ php foo.php` on the command line or by visiting `localhost/foo.php` in your browser, the *working directory* is `webroot/`. If you run `folder/bar.php`, the working directory is `webroot/folder`.

To make sure you're including files *relative to the file* the `include` is in, use something like:

```
include __DIR__ . '/folder/bar.php`;
```

That, or [alter your PATH](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to add your project root to it and always include relative to the project root. I prefer either file relative includes as shown above or [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling slightly to understand your question. I *think* your file structure looks like this:

- `users.php`
- `test` (folder)

  - `main.php`
  - `auth.php`
  - `db.php`

If so, to include `db.php` from `main.php`, all you need do is `include('db.php');`. The current folder is automatically in the path used to determine which files might be included.

In `auth.php`, you do `include('../test/main.php');`. This is unnecessary, since you are already in the `test` folder. You do `..` to get out of it, then you go straight back into it! You can simplify this with `include('main.php');`.