# Why is require_once not working

Tags: php, include-path

I'm working on a community written in PHP. I was just going to start working on a chat, so I created a new folder within the root one called "chat". And in that chat folder I created an "index.php" file. In that index.php file I wanna

```
require_once '../core/init.php';
```

The require_once fucntion works, but within my init.php file I

```
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php'.
```

this gives an error

> Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ooplr\core\init.php on line 26

Line 26 is

```
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php'.
```

Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2mtQ.png

Regards,

Gustaf

Comment: `require_once` isn't a function. It is a language construct.

Comment: The file does not exist. Be sure its really there and the path is correct.

Comment: ... but it should give you some insight

Comment: I've provided an image now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php Include() Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774467/php-include-issues)

Comment: Change . to ; gustaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do in a project like this is to define a constant pointing to the current working directory and then use it throughout your app.

For example, consider the following:

**chat/index.php**

```
<?php

// Constants
define('CWD', getcwd()); // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/chat

// Load Init Script
require CWD .'/../core/init.php'; // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/core/init.php

// Rest of code ...

?>
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php

// Load Sanitizer
require CWD .'/../functions/sanitize.php' // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/functions/sanitize.php

// Rest of the code

?>
```

etc...

---

Alternatively...

**chat/index.php**

```
<?php

// Constants
define('BaseDir', getcwd() .'/../'); // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/

// Load Init Script
require BaseDir .'core/init.php'; // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/core/init.php

// Rest of code ...

?>
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php

// Load Sanitizer
require BaseDir .'functions/sanitize.php' // points to C:/wamp/www/ooplr/functions/sanitize.php

// Rest of the code

?>
```

Comment: Looks nice. But do I have to define('CWD', getcwd()); in all files to get a unique one?

Comment: up to you. you can do it like I have shown, or replace `CWD` with `getcwd()` everywhere. It's more efficient to define a constant with the function value than use the function call everywhere again and again (less work?)

Comment: I've updated my answer with alternate way. This should give an idea why it's better to define one and use everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file exists and is in the right directory. As far as I recall, require (and include) will include the file starting from the "request"-directory. So if you call init.php, `require` will search in core/functions/sanitize.php.

Answer (score 0):

Asp your folder structure image `functions/sanitize.php` file not in core folder. so use this code.

```
require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';
```

Comment: That will make it work on only chat/index.php.

Comment: This code will work on all files.

Comment: I get an error on "root/index.php" when I use the code. Warning: require_once(../functions/sanitize.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ooplr\core\init.php on line 26

Comment: post your error here.

Answer (score 0):

you have `core/init.php` and `functions/sanitize.php` so need to use path back to one dir and include the file .

try

```
require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

`sanitize.php` is in `function` directory and `function directory` is not in `core` folder 

Now change

```
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

to

```
require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';
```